# Delayed in commando/apps in autostart

Tags: kernel

I experience a delay in apps I autostart in elementary OS. The problem occurs with the newer kernel releases I've noticed.

Any advise is appreciated.

My specs:
| AMD Ryzen 1700x 3.4 GHz | ASUS PRIME X370-A | 32 GB 2400 Mhz DDR4 |
| ASUS Nvidia 1070 8 GB | SSD 250 GB | HDD 1 TB |

```
Linux universe 5.3.0-62-generic #56~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 24 16:17:03 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: How do you configure the autostart for the apps?

Comment: I uses the gui for it Applications ---> Startup and the commando is a simple starting an app up - no fancy there.

Comment: Can You describe what you exactly do step by step? I know you open Startup. Then what? Maybe you are doing something wrong? Eventually you can reconsider to upgrade the kernel to 5.7.0 or newer.

Comment: I simply add a command eg. "steam -silent" into the startup.